# Oracle 12.1 Data types

Tags: oracle, plsql

According to the Oracle 12 documentation ( 1.1.6.4 ) on [Oracle's web site](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17906/chapter1.htm#NEWFTCH1) you are supposed to be able to create a varchar2 column with more than 4000 characters. Has anyone manged to do this as all I get is :-

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create table r1 ( c1 integer, c2 varchar2(32000));
create table r1 ( c1 integer, c2 varchar2(32000))
                                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype
```

Comment: You need to change the server parameter `max_string_size`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF55623 and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17615/refrn10321.htm#REFRN10321

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation also states](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF55623):

> Beginning with Oracle Database 12c, you can specify a maximum size of
>   32767 bytes for the VARCHAR2, NVARCHAR2, and RAW data types. You can
>   control whether your database supports this new maximum size by
>   setting the initialization parameter MAX_STRING_SIZE as follows:
>
> - If MAX_STRING_SIZE = STANDARD, then the size limits for releases prior to Oracle Database 12c apply: 4000 bytes for the VARCHAR2 and
>     NVARCHAR2 data types, and 2000 bytes for the RAW data type. This is
>     the default.
> - If MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED, then the size limit is 32767 bytes for the VARCHAR2, NVARCHAR2, and RAW data types.

So you need to set your [`MAX_STRING_SIZE` initialisation parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17615/refrn10321.htm) to make this work.

(I haven't had a chance to play with 12c yet, so I'm just going on what the docs say too at this point).

Comment: Thanks for that. I keep forgetting Oracle write down the same things in several places but not always with the same information ;-)

Comment: @RichardSpencer - well they wouldn't want to make life easy. That was linked to from the 1.1.6.4 section in the new features guide though, so you were only a click away.

Comment: - I wish I'd never asked the question. I have completly broken my database and can not start it up :-(